# Constrain entry widget to a min & max value, i.e. for Minutes constrain to 0 to 99, and for seconds constrain to 0 to 60 (not 59)

Tags: validation, range

I have a bunch of time entry widgets, grouped as mins:secs.
I want to constrain the minutes to 2 digits in the range 0 to 99, and the seconds also to 2 digits and range to 0 to 60, but as I type the number in. The entry widget can also be left empty (I'll check later that at least one of mins or secs has a valid number).

I've done this with Tcl, but can't get it to work with Python (yet) as a Python newbie.
This what I did for Tcl/Tk:

```
entry   $f1a.enMINS     -textvar    warm_mins   -width 2    -validate all -vcmd {ValidIntRng %P 0 $MaxMins}

proc ValidIntRng {val min max} {
    expr {($val eq "") || ([string is integer $val] && ($val >= $min) && ($val <= $max))}
}
```

Trying to write a "def"  that does the same job, but failing so far.

Any help to sort for python much appreciated.